# Bootstrap Nav Collapse Not Working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying this for a while and have tried several different reference documents. Attempting to do this purely in bootstrap HTML without CSS and JS (if possible) I am sure I am missing something...

https://jsfiddle.net/1b1L2zsw/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand ml-auto" href="#">Store</a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      </button>
        <div class="collaspe navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">New</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Collections</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">`
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: did you add/include the javascript file of Bootstrap to your file?

Comment: You're trying to do this without CSS? You're going to need CSS to apple styles to those classes (`navbar`, `container`, etc). Please provide the read of the page - maybe throw it on https://codepen.io for a full working example.

Comment: Can you post your entire code or JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1b1L2zsw/

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is you misspelled "collapse" in the class name for the `navbar-collapse` div. Although you do have an extra closing `</button>` tag.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsv5qnez/2/

Edit: You're absolutely going to need to include the Bootstrap JavaScript and CSS files too. There's no way to do what you want with pure HTML.

Comment: So thank you for that typo catch. To clarify I have a CSS file with:img {
 max-width:100%;
 display:inline-block;
}
ul {list-style:none;} + <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> However, no JS or jquery link. I'm still having trouble with the icon showing up locally